# Can't use sorting functions from pyspark.sql.functions on anonymous column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I'm working on a project that involved using pyspark. However, I'm running into py4j errors in using certain functions. Namely: `asc`, `desc` and all their variants. To reproduce, have a running `SaprkSession`, then run the following:

```py
from pyspark import functions as funcs

funcs.asc(funcs.col("foo"))
```

I obtain the following error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.asc. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method asc([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:276)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The following works just fine, however: `funcs.col("foo").asc()`. I assume this is a bug? Or am I just using the `functions` module incorrectly? Other funtions (`sin`, `min`, `stddev`, etc.) work just fine. The sorting functions seem to be the only problematic ones.

Version info:

- MacOS: 10.13.6
- Python: 3.7.3
- pyspark: 2.4.3
- py4j: 0.10.7

Update: The sorting functions do not work on explicit columns of a dataframe, either:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame({
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": ["a", "b", "c"]
    })
)
funcs.asc(df["a"])
```

This causes the same error.

Comment: Try `funcs.asc("foo")` or `funcs.asc("a")`.

Comment: @pault Wow. Easy enough. Thank you!

Comment: it's not obvious to me why passing in a `Column` doesn't work, but I'll see if I have time to dig through the source to find out.

Comment: @pault Looks like the functions `asc`, `desc`, `abs`, `min`, ..., are all made with the same wrapper function (`_create_function`, see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html). This function does a lookup for a corresponding JVM function that matches the call signature. It seems like `min`, `max`, `sqrt`, and others have an overloaded method corresponding to a `Column` input, but there is no JVM function for `asc` and `desc` that are overloaded for a `Column` input. If I get around to it, I might submit a JIRA for this functionality.

Comment: If you want to use columns instead of column names, the syntax is `col("foo").asc()`

Comment: @PMende I saw that but what's confusing is that the `_create_function` code has `col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col`, which implies that passing a `Column` should be supported. In any case, it may be worth adding your findings as an answer.